# how do i import blob and clob to hbase

Tags: hbase, hive, sqoop

I want to import tables which containing *blob* fields from oracle to *hbase* using *sqoop.*
I used below command:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.2.152.241:1521:QASOURCE
  --username devsrc --table fnd_lobs --password devsrc --hbase-table fndlobs
  --column-family cf --hbase-row-key file_id --columns file_id,file_name,file_data,upload_date,expiration_date,program_name
  --hbase-create-table --as-sequencefile --verbose -m1
```

Here `file_data` is a *blob* column.

The query is executing, but the output of *hbase* does not display the `file_data` field.

Output of hbase:

```
 238883                            column=cf:program_name, timestamp=1386805999370, value=PER_ADDR_gb_UK.pdf                          
 238883                            column=cf:upload_date, timestamp=1386805999370, value=2004-07-01 04:33:40.0                        
 238884                            column=cf:file_name, timestamp=1386805999370, value=/appltop/115/per/11.5.0/patch/115/publisher/tem
                                   plates/PER_WS1_gb_UK.pdf                                                                           
 238884                            column=cf:program_name, timestamp=1386805999370, value=PER_WS1_gb_UK.pdf                           
 238884                            column=cf:upload_date, timestamp=1386805999370, value=2004-07-01 04:33:41.0                        
 238885                            column=cf:file_name, timestamp=1386805999370, value=/appltop/115/per/11.5.0/patch/115/publisher/tem
                                   plates/PER_WS3_gb_UK.pdf                                                                           
 238885                            column=cf:program_name, timestamp=1386805999370, value=PER_WS3_gb_UK.pdf                           
 238885                            column=cf:upload_date, timestamp=1386805999370, value=2004-07-01 04:33:49.0                        
 238886                            column=cf:file_name, timestamp=1386805999370, value=/appltop/115/per/11.5.0/patch/115/publisher/tem
                                   plates/PER_WS4_gb_UK.pdf
```

The output is not displaying the `file_data` field. How to rectify this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Sqoop we have the option like --hbase-bulkload option, it enables to do bulkloading.

below is the command for sqoop bulk load

sqoop import -Dsqoop.hbase.add.row.key=true  --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@ipaddress:portnumber:DBName  --username username --table fnd_lobs_dupl --password pwd --hbase-table blobs --column-family cf --columns file_id,file_name,file_data,upload_date --hbase-row-key file_id  --hbase-create-table --inline-lob-limit 0 --hbase-bulkload --as-sequencefile -m1

Comment: Thanks for your reply,Its working now. I am able to import blob fields in hbase now.

Comment: Can we store the same files in HIVE?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which version of sqoop you are using. for now, at version 1.4.4, you cannot import blob to hbase.

> Sqoop’s direct mode does not support imports of BLOB, CLOB, or LONGVARBINARY columns.

But if you compile it from trunk following https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/trunk/COMPILING.txt

Apache Sqoop Trunk: https://github.com/apache/sqoop/tree/trunk

There is a new function. It will work because of `loadLargeObjects(lobLoader);` in `HBaseBulkImportMapper.java`

```
--hbase-bulkload     Enables bulk loading
```

> To decrease the load on hbase, Sqoop can do bulk loading as opposed to direct writes. To use bulk loading, enable it using --hbase-bulkload.

Again, 1.4.4 does not have this argument.